# How to delete multiple rows (using named parameters) in Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, sqlite, air

I am trying to delete multiple rows in the sqlite table in my Adobe AIR app (runtime 2.5).

Here is the statement, using the "IN" operator:

```
"DELETE FROM mylist WHERE tdId IN (tdId1, tdId2, tdId3, ...)";
```

Where tdId1, tdId2, etc. will be determined at runtime based on which row(s) the user chooses to delete. The user can delete arbitrary number of rows.

I've tried something like:

```
//delete statement text
"DELETE FROM mylist WHERE tdId IN :tdId";
//delete statement parameters: take 1. 
//Got "argument error: near ':tdId': syntax error"
deleteStmt.parameters[":tdId"] = "(26, 32)";
//delete statement parameters: take 2. 
//Also got "argument error: near ':tdId': syntax error"
var arr:Array = [26, 32];
deleteStmt.parameters[":tdId"] = arr;
```

How I go about deleting multiple rows?

[Edit] So it looks like the aforementioned cached statement with parameter [":tdId"] doesn't work when deleting multiple rows. When attempting to execute the delete statement multiple times in asynchronous mode, after the very first row in the queue is deleted, Flash throws the following error:

> "Error #3110: Operation cannot be
>   performed while SQLStatement.executing
>   is true."

It would seem too much of trouble to chain these deletes with a callback. So I guess I am using my last resort: building the sql at runtime. Conclusion: Cached statements can't be used in these kind of situations...

Comment: As the last resort, you can format query string with all those id in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you insert the parameter "(26,32)". As the parameter is not purely a substitution of value, it represents a variable to SQL, NOT A STRING. Hence you statement effectively became (or roughly) in your first take...

```
"DELETE FROM mylist WHERE tdId IN '(26,32)'"
```

Hence your error, due to the syntax... In your second take it gets worse...

```
"DELETE FROM mylist WHERE tdId IN *Array(26,32)*"
```

As the variable does not convert to a string value, this does not actually happen. But what happens is that when the interprater (SQL) tries to understand the code after the 'IN' text, it gets an ARRAY object, which it has completely no idea on what to do... Its not even a valid SQL type....

**Solution?** [I yet to fully test it, so please do]

```
var toDel:Array = [26,32]
//delete statement text
var baseStr:String = "DELETE FROM mylist WHERE tdId IN (";
var midStr:String = '';
//delete statement parameters: Processing parameter
for( var i = 0; i < toDel.length; i++ ) {
    deleteStmt.parameters[i] = toDel[i];
    if(midStr.length > 0) { midStr += ' , '; }
    midStr += '?';
}
deleteStmt.text = baseStr + midStr + ' )';
//Then execute
```

So what happens in this case is that u effectively execute...

```
"DELETE FROM mylist WHERE tdId IN ( :val1 , :val2 )"
```

In this way you still maintain the safe (good practice) use of parameters, without converting everything to a string.

**EDIT:** if you dun understand the use of parameter / '?' refer to : 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLStatement.html#parameters

Answer (score 0):

If the IN clause does not allow parameters, you can try old-school SQL style: append multiple

> " OR (tdId = :param" + paramCounter.toString() + ")"

to the SQL string